# Web Browser in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I am trying to make a simple browser in Windows Form Application. My first site, **"http://www.msn.com"** is loaded in browser on Form_Load. but when I set a valid url in **textbox1**, nothing comes up. and `webBrowser1.Document.Focus();` catch an error. "Object reference is null or ....", that common problem of null instance.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    myMethod("http://www.msn.com"); 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMethod(textbox1.Text);
}

public void myMethod(string url)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    webBrowser1.Document.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Where is the webBrowser1 initialization?

Comment: this is initialized in `InitializeComponent()`, which is in Form1() constructor.

Comment: In addition, this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581
seems to be kind of similar to your issue.
Might help you.

Comment: the null object is webbrowser1?

Comment: You cannot use the Document property until the DocumentCompleted event fires.  Using webBrowser1.Focus() ought to be sufficient.  Subscribing the event again in the method is wrong as well, that needs to be done only once.  It belongs in the constructor, trivially done right with the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Latest

Refer to @Hans Passant, I finally understand what part of the code is incorrect.

We subscribe from event in myMethod

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
```

and we **never** Unsubscribe from Event

Therefore we will increase the subscribe times and trigger the `browser_DocumentComplete`d **more than one time** if `webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted` happens

### Suggestions

```
//constructor
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //declare webBrowser1 before this
    //subscribe only once here
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
    //try these two if still fail
    //this.webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false; 
    //this.webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    myMethod("http://www.msn.com"); 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMethod(textbox1.Text);
}

public void myMethod(string url)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    webBrowser1.Document.Focus();
}

private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + " loaded";
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //unsubscribe here
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= browser_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `msn.com` is not coming here.

Comment: for me I can, but the title display **very weird** because my Absolute Uri becomes very long and weird. Did you put breakpoint to check what happen when you doing webBrowser1.Navigate()?

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.Domain' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: where ris browser_DocumentCompleted?

Comment: Form1_FormCLosing is not needed. Other Things are ok. Thanks for your cooperation. I have accepted it as a solution.

Comment: Just want to show good habit to dispose item that is disposable at form closing:-) thanks

Comment: While the form is closing, I have debugged that, `webbrowser1` executes it's own dispose method. So I think, it will not be necessary. :-) Welcome. And really thanks to you for your great effort.

Comment: Can you show me how you verify webbrowser execute its own dispose method while form closing in debugging mode? Does it show it's dispose detail to you?thanks:-)